# Repeat scroll items in UIScrollView to change the UIViewController like Gilt

Tags: iphone, ios

I do want to repeat scroll items in UIScrollView to change the UIViewController like Gilt.How can I do please ? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this.[SSRollingButtonScrollView](https://github.com/ninefifteen/SSRollingButtonScrollView)